# Generic method to read from json resource and return object

Tags: c#, json, extension-methods

I have an extension method which loads a resource from an assembly as text, this contains json

I then get this and deserialize it into my required type

```
var json = ResourceAssembly.GetResourceAsText("MyResourceFileName");
var list = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<MyObject>>(json);
```

Ideally I would like to do this in one single method GetFromResourceJson which takes the type that I want to serialize into and the filename, using generics

So the example above would simply be

```
var list = ResourceAssembly.GetFromResource<List<MyObject>>("MyResourceFilename");
```

How can I do this?

My current implementation for GetResourceAsText is below

```
 public static string GetResourceAsText(this Assembly assembly, string resourceToLoad)
 {
    var resourceName = GetFullResourceName(assembly, resourceToLoad);
    using var stream = assembly.GetManifestResourceStream(resourceName);
    var streamReader = new StreamReader(stream!);
    var result = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
    return result;
 }
```

Could someone help please?

Paul

Answer (score 1):

Am I missing something here?

```
public static T GetResource<T>(this Assembly assembly, string resourceToLoad)
{
    var resourceName = GetFullResourceName(assembly, resourceToLoad);
    using var stream = assembly.GetManifestResourceStream(resourceName);
    using var streamReader = new StreamReader(stream!);
    return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(streamReader.ReadToEnd());
}
```

You might even want to make it more generic by injecting the deserializer as a `Func<string, T>`, like this:

```
public static T GetResource<T>(this Assembly assembly, string resourceToLoad, Func<string, T> deserializer)
{
    var resourceName = GetFullResourceName(assembly, resourceToLoad);
    using var stream = assembly.GetManifestResourceStream(resourceName);
    using var streamReader = new StreamReader(stream!);
    return deserializer(streamReader.ReadToEnd());
}
```

and call it like this:

```
var list = ResourceAssembly
    .GetResource<List<MyObject>>("MyResourceFilename", JsonConvert.DeserializeObject);
```

This way you can use it to also deserialize xml (or any other string format, for that matter)

Comment: at least I am not the only one who though "What? Just do it."

Comment: @Paul - So basically your question was how to declare a generic method?